# eslint warning Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) no-loop-func in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

In my React project, I have a simple `.js` file with the following code

```
let oldInfo

function getChanges() {
    const newInfo = {};
    let keys = ["name", "age", "sex"];

    oldInfo = "one";
    for (const key in newInfo) {
        keys.forEach(subkey => {
            if (oldInfo[subkey] === newInfo[key])
                console.log(subkey);
        });
    }
}

getChanges();
```

And it gives a `no-loop-func` warning that though I researched a lot, couldn't figure out the risk.

```
Line 9:22:  Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'oldInfo'  no-loop-func
```

What is the risk? how can I fix this?

[Here](https://eslint.org/demo#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) is the warning on Eslint Demo editor

Comment: Did you get a chance to go through this - https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func

Comment: @Shyam Yes, I have gone through it, I was unable to find anything matching this one.

Answer (score 1):

> "This error is raised to highlight a piece of code that may not work
> as you expect it to and could also indicate a misunderstanding of how
> the language works"

From https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func

Also, read https://www.albertgao.xyz/2016/08/25/why-not-making-functions-within-a-loop-in-javascript/

In this particular case, you can fix it by defining the forEach callback function outside `getChanges` method(e.g. by the name `logIteration`) and modify forEach callback like this

```
 keys.forEach(logIteration)
```

Comment: What is the reason behind that? what possible error does it prevent?

Comment: https://www.albertgao.xyz/2016/08/25/why-not-making-functions-within-a-loop-in-javascript/ See this. It has to do with closures, when a function is defined it closes over values in it's scope and when the function is called it would use those values only.

This rule basically prevents accidentally hitting the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

For avoid this warning (error), you can use `for of` instead of `forEach`

```js
let oldInfo;

function getChanges() {
  const newInfo = {};
  let keys = ["name", "age", "sex"];

  oldInfo = "one";
  for (const key in newInfo) {
    for (let subkey of keys) {
      if (oldInfo[subkey] === newInfo[key])
        console.log(subkey);
    }
  }
}

getChanges();
```

> forEach expects a synchronous function.
>
> forEach does not wait for promises. Make sure you are aware of the implications while using promises (or async functions) as forEach callback.
>
> > Quote from [Array.prototype.forEach() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#sect3)

You can find good explanation and example on this page.

- [React – replacing an asynchronous .forEach() with for…of (and why it’s better that way)](https://www.tilcode.com/react-replacing-asynchronous-foreach-with-for-of/)