# Eslint no-loop-func for immediately invoked functions

Tags: javascript, eslint

I understand the importance of `no-loop-func` in codes like the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    funcs[i] = function() {
        return i;
    };
}
```

since the value of i changes.

But how can this be bad for the following function that is immediately invoked? why should we avoid that?

```
for (var i=10; i; i--) {
    (function() { return i; })(); //Or probably console.log(i) instead of return;
}
```

As stated [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func)

Comment: *"Or probably console.log(i) instead of return"* That's a pretty big difference. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, would return only make any use? since the value won't be used

Comment: I meant if you used it. In particular, if you retained the function and used its return value a after the loop. But I guess IIFE, you're not likely to do that (though technically it's possible).

Comment: *This rule disallows any function within a loop that contains unsafe references*, without promising to make further distinction between "actually works" and "really misbehaves" cases. I think that's why examples for both are shown, but only the last two would act strangely, where the explanation comments are provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint can only do so much analysis. While maybe it could be written to see that you're not *keeping* that function after the loop iteration is done (it's obvious in your example; less obvious cases would be harder), doing that might make ESLint's performance unacceptably slow.

Comment: Thank you very much, So would it be only a performance issue in this case, as long as we don't keep the function for other use? Except for the performance issue, would it be fine to go on with cases like in this question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014047/eslint-warning-function-declared-in-a-loop-contains-unsafe-references-to-variabl

Comment: @Abraham - Sorry, I'm not talking about the performance of **your** code, I'm talking about the performance of ESLint. :-) I've updated the answer to be clearer about that. ESLint doesn't raise the error if you use a `let` control variable, so apparently doesn't care about recreating functions without the closure-in-loops issue.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank you. I was having worrying about the my code's correctness when I got this warning. So can we say the code on the question link I sent you safe interms of integrity? and is it only ESLint giving non-point-specific general warning, but rather reminding me to consider check for no-loop-func? Thank you very much !

Comment: @Abraham - As long as the function is using `i` **during** that loop iteration, it's fine. But two things to consider: A) You might want to use `let` rather than `var` so that each loop iteration gets its own copy of `i`, and B) With block scoping (since ES2015), is there really any need for that IIFE? Happy coding!

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. I will proceed putting `// eslint-disable-next-line` above the `forEach` in question code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014047/eslint-warning-function-declared-in-a-loop-contains-unsafe-references-to-variabl, since I haven't used i out of the loop iteration.